# How to correct / shift subtitle time in SRT (SubRip) files?

Tags: delphi, shift, subtitle

How to correct/shift subtitle time forward and backward? Subtitle time format looks like this: 
`00:00:52,656 --> 00:00:56,326`

If subtitle and audio aren't synchronized, for example, subtitle shows up before voice/audio, then all times of subtitle lines (time format: `00:00:52,656 --> 00:00:56,326`) should be corrected.

So, if time of all subtitle lines must be changed/shifted for 2 sec. forward, then, this time for subtitle line: `00:00:52,656 --> 00:00:56,326` should be changed to: 
`00:00:54,656 --> 00:00:58,326`.

And this refers to all times in the subtitle file, not just one line of text/one time.

---

Example of how SubRip (.srt) file looks like:

```
1
00:00:52,656 --> 00:00:56,326
Kanalska Zona: Panama

2
00:00:56,335 --> 00:00:59,755
Francuzi su pokušali da izgrade
kanal pre Amerikanaca.
```

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with? Is this really specific to subtitles, or is it really about *any* time expressed numerically? What, specifically, do you want to "shift"? What does it mean to "shift" the time? What is your expected output, upon shifting the time?

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was not clear. It's edited and I think that is clearer now.

Comment: Good. Thanks. But again, which part are you having trouble with? It seems like you already understand the problem.

Comment: @Warren, to your update, have you seen how the *.sub file format looks like ?

Comment: Most *.sub and *.srt files looks like example that I just add in question, but they can have different look.

Comment: @Srdjan, I'd say you've shown the *.srt format which has quite fixed format. The *.sub file format looks different. Yeah, many video players can handle the file extension misuse, so what you can see as a *.srt file might be in real a *.sub file with a wrong extension.

Comment: What is widely known as a *sub* file (MicroDVD subtitle) does not even use time stamps, it uses frame numbers.

Comment: I'm with @SertacAkyuz. the `sub` format uses frames and depends on the  frame rate of the video. e.g. `{0}{20}Hello!`. OP is clearly want to use the SubRip (`srt`) format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Providing that the format of each line in your input is always `00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000`, then this routine will convert the string times to `TDateTime`, add or subtract the shift, and rewrite the line:

```
procedure ShiftSubtitleTimes(Lines: TStrings; Diff: TTime);
var
  FS: TFormatSettings;
  I: Integer;
  T1: TDateTime;
  T2: TDateTime;
begin
  // Ensure using the correct time separator
  FS.TimeSeparator := ':';
  // Parse each line separately
  for I := 0 to Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    // Convert the two time strings to time values
    if not TryStrToTime(Copy(Lines[I], 1, 8), T1, FS) then
      // But skip line in case of wrong format
      Continue;
    T1 := T1 + StrToInt(Copy(Lines[I], 10, 3)) / MSecsPerDay;
    T2 := StrToTime(Copy(Lines[I], 18, 8), FS);
    T2 := T2 + StrToInt(Copy(Lines[I], 27, 3)) / MSecsPerDay;
    // Add the shift
    T1 := T1 + Diff;
    T2 := T2 + Diff;
    // Rewrite the line
    Lines[I] := FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss,zzz --> ', T1, FS) +
      FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss,zzz', T2, FS);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  List: TStringList;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    List.LoadFromFile('Filename.dat');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Input:');
    Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(List);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('');
    // Shift 3,5 seconds backwards:
    ShiftSubtitleTimes(List, -3.5 / SecsPerDay);  
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Output:');
    Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(List);
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Due to your edit, now input may contain 'wrong' lines that need no conversion too.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your subtitle file with a free subtitle editor such as SubtitleEdit or Subtitle Workshop, you can easily adjust the times of all of your subtitles at once.

For SubtitleEdit you'll need to go to Synchronization > Adjust all times (Show earlier/later) > Adjust the amount of time you need to shift > Select if you want to apply it to all lines, only selected ones or from the selected onwards > Select either "Show earlier" or "Show later" > DONE!